# User Profile Synchronization is not provisioned, but User Profile services are started

Tags: user-profile-service, sharepoint-on-prem

I have problem in my SharePoint 2013 farm. User profile services and User profile sync service are already started. FIM and User Profile sync is working fine. We are able to see all the changes from AD to SharePoint.

But I am still seeing the error message in User Profile Synchronization is not provisioned in UPS application.

Could any one lease let me know why I am seeing this error?

Comment: where you are seeing the error? could you please add the error in your question?

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by trying out multiple options listed below

1. If you recently provisioned the UPS you need to reset IIS before you can create the sync connection.
2. Have you created Managed Metadata service application? If Restart doesn't work then create Manage metadata service application and then try.
3. Are there multiple servers in your farm?  Check if it is running on another server? This might be the cause.

Try these options and one of them has to work .

Answer (score 0):

in SharePoint 2013 use **"Active Directory Import"** instead of **"SharePoint Profile Synchronization"**  in **Configure synchronization Settings**

[image]

- Extremely fast performance
- Very reliable
- No FIM or extra sync service is required

more complete reviews:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/meacoex/2013/08/04/step-by-step-active-directory-import-for-sharepoint-2013/

http://www.harbar.net/archive/2012/07/23/sp13adi.aspx