# Why is 'User Profile Service Application' Job Failing?

Tags: 2013, active-directory, profile-sync, sync

I am new to Sharepoint and I am trying to troubleshoot a problem with importing  AD profiles on Sharepoint 2013

Anytime I run the 'User Profile Service Application' Job that is supposed to Synchronize the profiles, it fails shortly after and returns the error message:

> Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

This system was previously working and I am picking up the responsibility with no knowledge in the way it was initially setup.

This issue been going for a couple months before I began to notice it and I am at a loss as to where to start troubleshooting.

**EDITS:**

---

-Another answer shared mentioned that when you are importing from AD, you may not need the FIM service;
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/183098/64800

-My Sync connection is setup and populates when queried.

---

**If you need anymore information or have any ideas as to where I should start looking, please let me know.**

Comment: Pls add the SharePoint version

Comment: @TiagoDuarte I notice the second rated answer mentions that FIM is not required if you are using Active Directory Import.  Which is what I attempting.  Not sure if that makes it any different.

Thanks for the link though.